# I can't answer phone calls in some situations

Tags: calls, troubleshooting, motorola

I have a Motorola Citrus running android.

I know this is a lame question, but I am a newbie to android and smart phones.

Sometimes I will get a phone call I can't answer.

The incoming call screen will come up. On the left their will be a green circle with an icon of a phone receiver in it. On the right is a red circle with another icon in it.

Press either will not allow to take the call.

I'm guess a setting is messed up somewhere, but I have no idea so I thought I would ask.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of the Motorola methodology for answering or ignoring a call, but on my Samsung, merely touching the green or red button is insufficient; it requires a swipe to convey the intention. I believe this was re-engineered to prevent accidental accepts or hangups through a mere button press. The green button has green arrows and a swipe in the arrow direction from the button will accept the call. The same with the ignore swipe along the red arrows from the red button to indicate the call should go to voicemail.
UPDATE: Searching the Droid forums, I see that Motorola uses the same functionality for call answering, but many users would like to see the functionality changed to just a button press. Perhaps you are an advocate of the same technique. See this forum for suggestions others have made to change the functionality somehow through app replacement:
http://www.droidforums.net/forum/android-app-developers/37743-button-answer-call-instead-swipe.html

Comment: By "swipe" do you mean running my finger horizontally across the screen where the circle in the colored area is.  Thanks much!

Comment: @Steve - Exactly. Start within the button and drag your finger or thumb across in the arrow direction.

Comment: Maybe I will take time later to register so I can "put in a vote".  I'm a new user, and obviously I did not find that intuitive.  I had to get on the web to find out how to answer phone calls with their UI.  Thanks again.

Comment: I found this place for making feature requests for future versions of android.  I am going to ask for a button instead of a swipe:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list